# Finding IDs down a tree - query logic - PHP

Tags: php

I have the following table **folders**:

```
  id    name    childOf
------------------------
  1      A        0
  2      B        1
  3      C        0
  4      D        3
  5      E        2
  6      F        5
```

This forms a tree:

```
A
-B
--E
---F
C
-D
```

I am allowing drag and drop of the folders but need to prevent folders being dragged down into their own subfolders.

E.g. D to B is ok, D to E is ok, B to F is not ok as its dragging into its own tree, but F to B is ok as its dragging UP the tree.

QUESTION: If a user selects B and tries to drag it to F, how can I prevent that?

I am looking for logic, how would one say it, and then code it, that B to F is not ok but F to B is.

Comment: It is exceedingly hard to manage trees in an RDBMS with only a child-parent relationship to work with. Have you looked into any of the common methods to work with trees in RDBMSs, like MPTT trees or paths?

Comment: Multidimensional array where key=id? Each key is folder and the sub key a children, however I don't think it's so optimized as you should iterate over the first array key. Example: [1]->[2]->[5]->[6], [2]->[5]->[6], [3]->[4], [4], [5]->[6], [6], the first key is the retrieved I'd from the attribute or whatever

Answer (score 4):

With your current DB schema I see only the option of multiple select statements. You would have to check upwards or downwards the tree until you hit the root or the last child (like in nietonfirs answer).

I for myself would add a fourth column to the table, containing the full path:

```
id   name   childOf   pathToFolder
----------------------------------
1      A        0      ,1,
2      B        1      ,1,2,
3      C        0      ,1,3,
4      D        3      ,1,3,4,
5      E        2      ,1,2,5,
6      F        5      ,1,2,5,6,
```

There are several ways to use this new data. One way is, if someone wants to move B, get a list of valid destinations: `SELECT id FROM folders WHERE pathToFolder NOT LIKE ',1,2,%'`

These kind of operations are not the fastest but very handy.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there'd be a method that would take ids of both target and destination (or whole data objects, whatever), and check if target is in destinations path or not. If it is, then the method would return false or throw an exceptions, else it would return true. That method could be introduced to your directory copying code flow as a control structure.

Personally, for hierarchical data structures I'd go with implementing it as a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). It can be a hassle to set-up and fixing nested set can get tedious, but I find it very convinient for checking relations between nodes, and getting whole subtrees.

Here's a PHPUnit test with a partial and somewhat naive implementation of my idea:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class ParentingSucks
{

    public $data = array();

    public function isAllowed($targetId, $destId)
    {
        $target = $this->getById($targetId);
        $dest = $this->getById($destId);
        $parent = $this->getById($dest['childOf']);

        $isAllowed = true;
        while ($parent) {
            if ($parent['id'] == $targetId) {
                $isAllowed = false;
                break;
            }

            $parent = $this->getById($parent['childOf']);
        }

        return $isAllowed;
    }

    public function getById($id)
    {
        if (isset($this->data[$id])) {
            return $this->data[$id];
        }
        return array();
     }
}

class HowIMetYourParentDir extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     * @dataProvider generate
     */
    public function droppingOnParentNotAllowed($data, $target, $dest, $outcome)
    {

        $stub = $this->getMock('ParentingSucks', null);
        $stub->data = $data;

        $result = $stub->isAllowed($target, $dest);

        $this->assertEquals($result, $outcome, 'Oh no!');
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $fakeData = array(
            1 => array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'A', 'childOf' => 0),
            2 => array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'B', 'childOf' => 1),
            3 => array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'C', 'childOf' => 0),
            4 => array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'D', 'childOf' => 3),
            5 => array('id' => 5, 'name' => 'E', 'childOf' => 2),
            6 => array('id' => 6, 'name' => 'F', 'childOf' => 5),
        );
        return array(
            array(
                $fakeData,
                2, // target
                6, // dest
                false, // outcome
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                4,
                2,
                true,
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                4,
                2,
                true,
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                3,
                4,
                false,
            ),
        );
    }
}              false, // outcome
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                4,
                2,
                true,
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                4,
                2,
                true,
            ),
            array(
                $fakeData,
                3,
                4,
                false,
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Variable/function/class names will probably not fit your domain model, so never mind them.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. With your current tree structure, you could iterate recursively (or using stack) over parents of the element you are appending to; If one of parents is equal to the appended element, simply return error. You could also perform that check in javascript in order to provide better user experience (why even allow dragging element to it's own child :)); This approach however could be a little slow with really big trees, BUT writes are really cheap.
2. You could make dealing with your tree a whole lot easier by reworking your tree structure  a nested set; I will not go into deep details of nested sets, as you can read these on this page: [About nested sets](http://docs.cartalyst.com/nested-sets-2/overview/about). Instead, I will give you a quick insight of what is possible with nested sets. First, your table would look like this:

```
    id    name      lft   rgt
    ---------------------------
    1      A        1     8
    2      B        2     7
    5      E        3     6
    6      F        4     5
    3      C        9     12
    4      D        10    11
```

It may look strange at the first glance, but don't worry about it for now.

With that you may easily check if one node is parent of another: `$static->lft > $appended->lft && $static->rgt < $appended->rgt`, and if that is true, then `$appended` is parent of `$static` and you may throw an error;

Do you need to:

- retrieve all parents of a given node? Select 
  `WHERE lft < $node->lft and rgt > $node->rgt`;
- retrieve all descendants? Select `WHERE lft > $node->lft and rgt < $node->rgt`
- retrieve all siblings? Add extra `level` column, and that's easy-peasy

But wait wait wait, *How do I insert a new node into that structure?* you may ask. Fortunately there is no need to re-invent the wheel, as nested sets are quite popular. You could use implementation like this one: https://github.com/riquito/Baobab/ and just focus on your app;

Check out some examples from the repo: https://github.com/riquito/Baobab/blob/master/src/examples/animals.php

```
$root_id=$tree->appendChild(NULL,array("name"=>'Animals'));

$vertebrates_id   = $tree->appendChild($root_id,array("name"=>"Vertebrates"));
$invertebrates_id = $tree->appendChild($root_id,array("name"=>"Invertebrates"));
```

As you can see, you don't have to touch `lft` or `rgt` values as someone already wrote that part for you. If you use Propel or Doctrine things are even easier as they both support nested sets.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is fairly simple:

**A folder `f` can be dragged to a target folder `t` if and only if `f<>t` and `f`
is not an ancestor of `t`.**

Since the question is tagged as [php](/questions/tagged/php) and no RDBMS is specified, I will make the assumption that your folders live in a php array like the following:

```
$namespace=array(
  1=>array('name'=>'A','parent'=>0),
  2=>array('name'=>'B','parent'=>1),
  3=>array('name'=>'C','parent'=>0),
  4=>array('name'=>'D','parent'=>3),
  5=>array('name'=>'E','parent'=>2),
  6=>array('name'=>'F','parent'=>5),
  );
```

To decide whether `$f` is an ancestor of `$t`, we should start with `$t` and walk the tree upwards until either (1) we find `$f` or (2) we hit *a* root (not *the* root, since there are multiple roots in your namespace). So consider the following function:

```
function is_ancestor($f,$t)
  {
  global $namespace;
  $are_equal=($f==$t);
  $t_parent=$namespace[$t]['parent'];
  $is_root=!isset($namespace[$t_parent]);
  return $are_equal || (!$is_root && is_ancestor($f,$t_parent));
  }
```

I think it's pretty straightforward. Two things though: (1) apparently, the parameters are the folder *ids*, and (2) despite the name, the function checks not only if `$f` is an ancestor of `$t`, but also if they are equal.

You can see the whole concept in action, in [this php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gmv-wpj).

Answer (score 0):

Just check for the parents until you hit your root folder? In pseudo-code

```
// targetFolder is the target folder where the folder is going to be moved
// while sourceFolder is the folder that's moved.
parents = targetFolder.getParents();
if (parents.contains(sourceFolder)) {
    // don't allow the operation
}
```

Comment: Um... I think it's the other way around: If the _source_  is an ancestor of the _destination_, the operation shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @geomagas Exactly. I'll update my example to be more clear on that.

Answer (score 0):

The suboptimal way is to simply compute all subfolders of a given folder, and then check if the destination folder is part of them. Could look like this:

```
getSubfolders(folder):
    oneLevelDeepSubfolders = subfolders with child-of field == folder.id
    allSubfolders = []
    for subfolder in oneLevelDeepFolders:
        allSubfolders += getSubfolders(subfolder);
    return allSubfolders;
```

Then just check if your destination folder is in getSubfolders(folder).

You might want to speed this up by making another table that pre-computes the subfolder relationship for arbitrary depths so you don't have to recursively compute it every time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This question reminds me about things in my language classes. So I come up with a solution like this: 
Let me build your tree in an imaginary way. I will say R for root (id:0) and -1 for the end.

```
R:AC
A:B
B:E
E:F
F:-1
C:D
D:-1
```

But it's not enough if we want to do things fastly.
Let's add these too:

```
R:BC
R:EC
R:FC

R:BD
R:ED
R:FD
```

Let me organize things for you:

```
R:AC
R:AD *I added this one
R:BC
R:EC
R:FC
R:BD
R:ED
R:FD
R:A * this one too
R:C * this one too
A:B
B:E
E:F
C:D
F:-1
D:-1
```

This should be enough. 
So, you said

> E.g. D to B is ok, D to E is ok, B to F is not ok as its dragging into its own tree, but F to B is ok as its dragging UP the tree.

Let's see, D to B is OK? We should check it from right to left. Where is D? Oh yes, there you are.. R:BD! So, it's ok if they are together? Yes, it's ok. D to E? R:ED! yeap, it's ok too. B to F? Let's look BF together... no ha? So, B at the right side... there is A:B , So Let's check for A R:A! boom! B

This was just a suggestion for looking things in a different way. It can be done by different outlooks. But I really think using a language grammar like this would help. It can be created on the air or depending on the situation, it can be done as a map file. But complexity in lots of situations are really low. Good luck with finding the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your problem. The algorithm is really simple.

Every time your PHP gets called you first check if the folder is not a sub folder of the target folder.
Now in your case this is not going to work. You should not use numeric id's to save folders and files you should as all operating systems use a file path.

Just like this:

```
url                    type     description
-------------------------------------------------
ROOT/folder            2        Image folder...
ROOT/hallo             1        Hallo directory..
ROOT/hallo/subfolder   1        I am a sub dir..
```

Now you only need one column but it will be a full text index. When you want to check if a folder is not parent of its own sub folder you simply check the url.

Like when I draw `ROOT/hallo` To `ROOT/hallo/subfolder` You simply do this:

ROOT/hallo = 10 character

ROOT/hallo/subfolder = 20 character

```
<?php

    $selected_folder = 'ROOT/hallo';
    $subject_folder = 'ROOT/hallo/subfolder';

    $length = strlen($selected_folder);
    if($selected_folder != substr($subject_folder,0,$length)){
         echo 'go';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Can not relocate folder to its own subfolder';
    }

?>
```

Comment: With your suggested database structure you have absolutely no way to reliably select a specific row because there is no unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged with PHP, and you are talking about Drag and drop, you will need to classes to represent tree behavior in PHP as well as in javascript

for PHP, I would like to suggest you to go through the implementation of TreeBehavior class of cake-php framework, which adds tree behavior to any model and expect you to have your table structure as suggested by Adam.

for Javascript implementation i observed that YUI [tree module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/modules/tree.html)

implements trees for javascript

there is one more library which perhaps supports Drag and Drop, find it  [here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html)

I hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check destination path. If one of parent node is source node then chain will be broken and display error. For example:

```
<?php
define("ROOT_NODE_ID",0);
function getChildOf($nodeId){
   // some code to get id value of parent node and assign it to $parentId
   return $parentId;
}

$sourceId = 2; // Node B
$destinationId = 6; // Node F
$error = false;

$tmpParentId = getChildOf( $destinationId );
while($tmpParentId != ROOT_NODE_ID){
    if($tmpParentId == $sourceId ){
        $error=true;
        break;
    }
    $tmpParentId = getChildOf( $tmpParentId );
}
```

This method allows use **indexes with integer** values and *NOT USE string functions*. String functions maybe much slow whan work with int type fields.
Also you can keep this table structure without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions and get the all top parents of each of the ids i.e. from B to A & similarly from F to it's topmast parent F to c and store the ids in two different arrays.Now check thet whether something is common in the two arrays or not.If common cn drag else can't be dragged